# Where can I find more detailed help for ShowUI in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am unable to find clear information anywhere on how to use the ShowUI functions.  I've created a function that searches for movie information in an effort to easily update my movie list.  The function works fine and I can add the content to a `New-Window` but I would love to be able to add a button that closes it or perhaps close it after a certain period. For the latter, I run into the window taking priority until it is closed, which makes no sense for what I am trying to do.  My code is below.

```
function movie($sss,$ii){
cls
$a = ((wget "https://www.allmovie.com/search/all/$sss" ).allelements|where tagname -match "LI"|where class -match 'movie')|select *
$a = ($a.innertext -join(";") -isplit('movie') -split(';'))

if($ii -lt ''){

    $a = $a[4] -replace('\s\s')

 }else{
    $a -replace("(.?img|DB|@.*|_images*|.com).*|\s\s|(""\W)", "")|out-host

    BREAK
}
$moviesearch = new-window $B -TaskbarItemInfo "Movie Search"  -Background black -Foreground red -width 500 -Height 300 -top 100 -left 100  -FontSize 16 -show|out-null
}
```

Comment: [ShowUI](https://github.com/ShowUI/ShowUI) is based on [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/)

Comment: @iRon, I understand that but those help articles only show content for C+ and XAML which is not incredibly helpful for me in Powershell and I don't know anything about the C+ language.  Is there not a guide for that specifically, or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: Xaml works the same in PowerShell as in C. In other words, you need to learn both PowerShell and WPF (and optionally the ShowUI wrapper) to build an UI.